# Loading image not showing while loading html

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

I am trying to show a loading image before HTML content loads, but it's not appearing before the HTML loads for some reason:

You can see it in action here:
http://www.machinas.com/wip/esprit/games/2013_Spring_game/html/

click Play >>> Start the game... this then loads in the HTML.

HTML

```
<div id="loading-image"></div>
```

CSS

```
#loading-image{
    background:url(../img/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;    
    margin-left:-8px;
    display:none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('body').on('click', '.mch-ajax', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mch-overlay').fadeOut(300);
        $( ".content" ).load("game.html", function() {
            $("#loading-image").show();
                var myBackgroundImage = new Image();
                myBackgroundImage.src = "http://www.machinas.com/wip/esprit/games/2013_Spring_game/html/img/bg-map.png";        
                myBackgroundImage.onload = function () {
                    $("#loading-image").hide();
                    $( ".map" ).fadeIn(300);
                    $( ".note" ).delay(400).fadeIn(700);
                    $( ".route" ).delay(800).fadeIn(700);
                    $( ".start-btn" ).delay(1200).fadeIn(700);
                };

        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument you post to `.load()` is the *callback*, which is executed *after* the content has loaded. You simply need to move the loading image logic before you call `.load()`.

```
$('body').on('click', '.mch-ajax', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mch-overlay').fadeOut(300);
        $("#loading-image").show();
        $( ".content" ).load("game.html", function() {
                var myBackgroundImage = new Image();
                myBackgroundImage.src = "http://www.machinas.com/wip/esprit/games/2013_Spring_game/html/img/bg-map.png";        
                myBackgroundImage.onload = function () {
                    $("#loading-image").hide();
                    $( ".map" ).fadeIn(300);
                    $( ".note" ).delay(400).fadeIn(700);
                    $( ".route" ).delay(800).fadeIn(700);
                    $( ".start-btn" ).delay(1200).fadeIn(700);
                };

        }); 
    });
```

Comment: In that case I'd remove the `display:none` to the loading image to make sure it is appearing where you think it should. It could be hidden or the image not loading for whatever reason. Or even it's loading so quickly you don't notice it.